# What's the meaning of this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> 子供達の負担になりたくない。

なりたくない meaning is: don't want to be or don't want to become?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the context. If you are already  **[負担]【futan】** *a burden or a load* of your children, the answer is "be".
If you are afraid of being a *futan* of your children in the future, the answer is "become".